# Localization of Azure SQL Reporting

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-vm-role

What is the recommended way of localizing Azure SQL Reporting reports ? 
I found some articles with resources files in an seperate assembly, for example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294636/Localizing-SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-Reports 
But I think i can only do this if i run my own server, as i don't know how to deploy a seperate assembly onto the azure reporting server.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Azure Reporting** is a closed system. If you need to customize the reporting server for localization, you will need to [run a SQL Azure VM](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-sql-server/) and configure **Reporting Services**. Once configured, you have full access to the server to deploy any assemblies you require.